# Why is casting needed

Tags: java, casting

The following works as intended:

```java
public boolean equals(Object otherObject) {
    if (otherObject instanceof Employee) {
        Employee toCompare = (Employee) otherObject;
        if (this.getLastName().equals(toCompare.getLastName()) && this.idNumber == toCompare.idNumber) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

My question is why doesn't this work also:

```java
public boolean equals(Object otherObject) {
    if (otherObject instanceof Employee) {            
        if (this.getLastName().equals(otherObject.getLastName()) && 
           this.idNumber == otherObject.idNumber) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

What was the reason they left this out of the compiler? Or, what does toCompare have that otherObject doesn't have?  They both point to the same location so what's the difference?

Comment: The type of `otherObject` is `Object`, so you cannot call methods specific to `Employee`.

Comment: The cast is needed because `otherObject` is of type `Object`, not `Employee`. With Java 14 as an experimental feature and from Java 16 onwards (I believe), you can write `if(otherObject instanceof Employee toCompare)` to omit the explicit cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're talking about is so-called flow type tightening. You want this:

```
Object foo = ...;
if (foo instanceof String) {
  foo.toLowerCase();
}
```

To work because specifically within the confines of that `if` block, `foo`, surely, is a String.

There are some fundamental problems with that idea:

- Imagine `foo` is not a local variable but a field. Surely this should still work. Except... fields can be changed on the fly by other threads. So should the language *not* apply this principle for fields, but *do* apply it for method-locals? That sounds like you're just opening the door for somebody else to ask an incredulous question about why in the blazes there's a difference.
- That would mean if you then change `foo` inside the `if`, things get a bit bizarre. What should happen here:

```
Object foo = ...;
if (foo instanceof String) {
  if (Math.random() < 0.00005) foo = 5;
  foo.toLowerCase();
}
```

That clearly should not work - its unlikely but possible that `foo` isn't a string when you call `foo.toLowerCase()`. So here it wouldn't work?

You hopefully see the general issue of taking inference too far. It makes trying to debug the situation when you write some code and it doesn't do what you wanted it to incredibly complicated. It makes the compiler extremely complicated.

Now, that doesn't mean that it's a bad idea to add it. This is merely an explanation for something much, much simpler:

- **It is understandable that the JDK engineers, at the time java 1.0 was released, set it up this way.**

Even if you think it is wrong, that's not the point. The point is simply that it is understandable that the choice was made not to flow type this structure.

Which gets us to the next point:

### ... and now we are stuck with it

Introducing flow typing *now* would **break backwards compatibility**. Weird, but true - that's because in java, method parameters are part of a method's identity, and thus, changing types can make the exact same code now refer to a completely different method. This is current, vanilla java, try it out if you like:

```
class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object a = "foo";
    String b = "foo";
    System.out.println(test(a));
    System.out.println(test(b));
  }

  public static void test(Object x) {
    System.out.println("foo(Object)");
  }

  public static void test(String x) {
    System.out.println("foo(String)");
  }
}
```

This will print `foo(Object)`, then `foo(String)`. You might find that weird - in both cases, the object passed is of type String. That's because which of the two methods to go with is decided by the compiler, not at runtime. Java does have dynamic typing but it applies solely to when you override methods, which requires not just that the name is identical, but also that the parameter types are. Not the case here.

We can do another deep dive on why one might design a language like that, but at some point we'll be here, 4871 years from now, with you asking 'sooo, about that big bang'. It certainly is well beyond the scope of this question.

At any rate, given that this is how java works, adding flow typing breaks things. After all, imagine in the above code I did:

```
Object q = "Hello";
if (q instanceof String) {
  test(q);
}
```

Then current java would print `test(Object)` whereas if you add flow typing, you get `test(String)` and that is not backwards compatible.

### The good news

Just because other languages did it this way doesn't mean java has to follow and break stuff, nor that java just has to sit there and regret.

You just add the feature differently. Which is where patterns come in. New java features, which is a **vastly** more complicated feature than just this, but one of the many, many things it can do, is:

```
Object foo = "x";
if (foo instanceof String bar) {
  bar.toLowerCase();
}
```

This works fine, and avoids the backwards incompatibility issues. It also avoids the confusion about '.. but what if `foo` is a field that gets changed halfway through (irrelevant; the test and assignment to variable `bar` is atomic)', it avoids the problem if reassigning it (feel free, but variable `foo` is of type `Object` and variable `bar` is of type `String`, and nothing is going to change this, so there is no confusion there either).

It also allows deconstruction, pattern matching, and far, far more.

If you'd like to know more, these things are discussed at extreme length (you'll spend WEEKS reading if you want to know all the details) on the openjdk mailing lists. valhalla-dev, amber-dev, core-lib-dev might be interesting for this. Here is the main page of the [amber-dev mailing list](https://mail.openjdk.org/mailman/listinfo/amber-dev).

Answer (score 3):

The fields and methods you can access on a variable depend on its static type. `otherObject` is of type `Object`, so you cannot call methods specific to `Employee`.

[Pattern matching for `instanceof`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/pattern-matching-instanceof-operator.html) makes this simpler to write, though.

```java
if (otherObject instanceof Employee emp) {
    return this.getLastName().equals(emp.getLastName()) && 
           this.idNumber == emp.idNumber;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it doesn't seem to answer my question.  Both otherObject and toCompare point to the same place.  Where is the static type stored if not with the object?  But besides that, it would seem trivial to allow this so why wasn't it?  I'm sure there's a good reason I just can't figure out what it is.  Is there a hash table somewhere that stores addresses and object types as opposed to storing  or embedding the type into the object location?  What would be the reason for doing that?

Comment: @DCR Sure, they point to the same place, but the two variables have different types. If you declare something as an object, then you can only use Object methods. How would the compiler know at compile time that the actual type is something else? And how would it be able to check that you're using it correctly?

Comment: so if they point to the same place but their types are different, where is the type actually stored?  If type was stored with the object then it would be easy to do this.  Why isn't it?  I mean, If we have String x = new String() someplace in the computer String has to be associated with x.

Comment: @DCR Consider a method that accepts an object. Does it make sense to call Employee methods on the parameter when the input can be **any** Object?

Comment: If you're asking why the compiler doesn't "know" that `otherObject` is an `Employee` after the `instanceof` check, then the answer is likely that it's not worth it to add additional rules to cover this specific case where you can just cast. The rule can remain that the compiler only allows calling methods that are visible on the type of the variable. @DCR

Comment: I'm asking why it doesn't know this before the instanceof check.  when I try to use a method that doesn't exist I know this immediately in my ide.  It says method not found. Why doesn't the compiler check for each instanceof - I mean isn't there somewhere stored the object name and the different instanceof objects it's associated with?

Comment: for instance if I have an object that is a Shape, Rectangle and Square and I over ride some method the compiler knows which one to use.

Comment: @DCR Before the instanceof check, the object could be of any type. You could call `.equals(new Object())` for instance. Then it definitely is not valid to call Employee methods.

Comment: @DCR Now, after the check, the only answer is that the JLS does not add a special rule for the compiler deducing a more specific type from the context. It is likely to be too much work for very little gain. This example is simple, but it can rapidly get extremely difficult for the compiler to narrow down a type in a deeply nested context. And it doesn't really bring all that much benefit. Saving a line is not really what Java is about.

Comment: thanks, not trying to save a line just trying to understand the language and compiler better.  It seems trivial and it would seem the information is there and in some ways like with my over ride example the compiler is smart enough to sort this out.